# Flutter show and hide container on scrolling ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I show a `Container` with animation on scrolling `ListView` down and hide it when scrolling up.

The video I am attaching is not exact implementation I want but it is just to give you an idea.

[image]

**Sample video**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tMqm.jpg

---

**Edit:**

Every time I scroll down, I need to show the `Container` and every time I scroll up, I want to hide it. It shouldn't depend on the index of the `ListView`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726381/flutter-sliver-container

Comment: so when scrolling down you want to show it ("scrolling listview down=> show the container") or hide it ("when i starting scrolling down listview. then Container should be hide")? what do you want to do when scrolling down actually?

Comment: @pskink show and hiding the Container top of ListView

Comment: what do you want to do when **scrolling down**? you cannot show and hide at the same time

Comment: @pskink scrolling down cause of hide the container and scrolling up cause of show the container

Comment: @pskink no, my idea is simple than your link. https://imgur.com/a/auEzJQk

Comment: so you need `SliverPersistentHeader` (some basic samples are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58097429/2252830)

Comment: It can be achieved by using SliverWidgets. There are good tutorials on youtube for that.

Comment: I am out of workplace and once I get back, I'll post an answer. You don't need to use SliverPersistentHeader, I think my friend (pskink) misunderstood your question, I just edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: You just want to use Container ? or SliverWidgets is ok for you ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question properly, is this what you are trying to achieve?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // Height of your Container
  static final _containerHeight = 100.0;

  // You don't need to change any of these variables
  var _fromTop = -_containerHeight;
  var _controller = ScrollController();
  var _allowReverse = true, _allowForward = true;
  var _prevOffset = 0.0;
  var _prevForwardOffset = -_containerHeight;
  var _prevReverseOffset = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_listener);
  }

  // entire logic is inside this listener for ListView
  void _listener() {
    double offset = _controller.offset;
    var direction = _controller.position.userScrollDirection;

    if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      _allowForward = true;
      if (_allowReverse) {
        _allowReverse = false;
        _prevOffset = offset;
        _prevForwardOffset = _fromTop;
      }

      var difference = offset - _prevOffset;
      _fromTop = _prevForwardOffset + difference;
      if (_fromTop > 0) _fromTop = 0;
    } else if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      _allowReverse = true;
      if (_allowForward) {
        _allowForward = false;
        _prevOffset = offset;
        _prevReverseOffset = _fromTop;
      }

      var difference = offset - _prevOffset;
      _fromTop = _prevReverseOffset + difference;
      if (_fromTop < -_containerHeight) _fromTop = -_containerHeight;
    }
    setState(() {}); // for simplicity I'm calling setState here, you can put bool values to only call setState when there is a genuine change in _fromTop
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ListView")),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _yourListView(),
          Positioned(
            top: _fromTop,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: _yourContainer(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _yourListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 100,
      controller: _controller,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $index")),
    );
  }

  Widget _yourContainer() {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 1 - (-_fromTop / _containerHeight),
      child: Container(
        height: _containerHeight,
        color: Colors.red,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("Your Container", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: as usually overcomplicated

Comment: @Eugene Haha, your solution was good for older post but OP edited the question saying he wants to track every time a scroll happen, so I had to use this approach. Happy to see if you come up with some simple one.

Comment: How could I do the same thing, just the other way around? When "FORWARD" the Container would appear, when "REVERSE" the Container would disappear.

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro I'm not in front of my computer, will get back to you once I get there. it should be easy though.

Comment: @ CopsOnRoad, achieve with these modifications:
if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
    ...
    var difference = _prevOffset - offset;
    _fromTop = _prevForwardOffset + difference;
    if (_fromTop < -_containerHeight){
        _fromTop = -_containerHeight;
      }
    } else if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
     ...
      var difference = offset - _prevOffset;
      _fromTop = _prevReverseOffset - difference;
      if (_fromTop > 0){
        _fromTop = 0;
      }
    }
   ...
} Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double HEIGHT = 96;
    final ValueNotifier<double> notifier = ValueNotifier(0);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test')),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (n) {
                if (n.metrics.pixels <= HEIGHT) {
                  notifier.value = n.metrics.pixels;
                }
                return false;
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 42,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 64,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            HideableWidget(height: HEIGHT, notifier: notifier),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HideableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final ValueNotifier<double> notifier;

  HideableWidget({@required this.height, @required this.notifier});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, value - height),
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, How could i achieve the same in reverse order.(I want to hide the container when I scroll).

Comment: @ARUNBALAJI just reverse the condition -> 
if (n.metrics.pixels >= HEIGHT) {
                                      notifier.value = n.metrics.pixels;
                                    }

Comment: reverse not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution of your problem. Here is the demo code

```
 class _DemoState extends State<WidgetDemo> {
      ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
      bool isVisible = true;

      @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();
        scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            if (isVisible)
              setState(() {
                isVisible = false;
              });
          }
          if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward) {
            if (!isVisible)
              setState(() {
                isVisible = true;
              });
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new CustomScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  new SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    sliver: new SliverList(
                      delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                        <Widget>[
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                          const Text('My temp data'),
                          const Text('Wow its working'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  height: isVisible ? 60.0 : 0.0,
                  child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Center(child: Text("Container")),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```