# Flutter show widgets on top of ListView which can slide on scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was able to solve [this part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254569/flutter-show-and-hide-container-on-scrolling-listview), and now I want to put one more `Container` at the bottom of the screen say `ContainerB`.

**Expectation:**

When scrolling down the `ListView` (i.e. `ScrollDirection.reverse`) I want Top `Container` say **ContainerA** to slide up from top and at the same time Bottom `Container` say `ContainerB` to slide up from bottom
and vice versa on sliding up the `ListView` with `fade` effect too.

Can anyone use the exiting code or something new to help me out on this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Now you want the reverse of it?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad i want to have another widget bottom of screen and you right, reverse of it with fade effect too

Comment: @Eugene my code is previous implementation on this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298462/1830228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

---

Probably this will help.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _controller = ScrollController();
  static final double _height = 120;
  double _top = 0, _topList = _height;
  double _offsetA = 0, _offsetB = 0, _savedA = 0, _savedB = 0;
  var _tookA = false, _tookB = false, _fadeContainer = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(listener);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ListView")),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: _topList,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: _buildListView(),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: _top,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: _fadeContainer ? 1 + (_top / _height) : 1,
              child: _buildContainer(title: "ContainerA", color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: -_height - _top,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: _fadeContainer ? (-_top / _height) : 1,
              child: _buildContainer(title: "ContainerB", color: Colors.teal),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void listener() {
    double offset = _controller.offset;

    _topList = _height - offset;
    if (_topList < 0) _topList = 0;

    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      _tookB = false;
      if (!_tookA) {
        _tookA = true;
        _offsetA = offset;
      }

      var difference = offset - _offsetA;
      _top = _savedB - difference;
      if (_top <= -_height) _top = -_height;
      _savedA = _top;
    } else if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      _tookA = false;
      if (!_tookB) {
        _tookB = true;
        _offsetB = offset;
      }

      var difference = offset - _offsetB;
      _top = _savedA - difference;
      if (_top >= 0) _top = 0;
      _savedB = _top;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _height + 16),
      itemCount: 16,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $i")),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContainer({String title, Color color}) {
    return Container(
      height: _height,
      color: color,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you attach simple screenshot of your implementation please?