# how to expand child of listview so that all child occupy maximum width in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a listview to show all available names.. taken text widget inside container..

here i want same width for all name's container inside listview...

like..if names are only 2 ..these should occupy totalwidth/2 and so on for more names

like if names are 4. ..these should occupy totalwidth/4

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: names.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: Center(child: Text(names[index])),
              ),
            );

          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i am getting this one...this not i want
[image]

Comment: 1. Determine the viewport size, and divide it by the number of elements you want to display (take padding into account), and then just set the width of your `Text` widgets to that value.... or 2. Use a `ConstrainedBox` and set the minimum size of each `Text` widget.

Comment: If all the names will fit into one row and you don't need scrolling, then use a `Row` and wrap all `Text` widgets with `Expanded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the device width in a variable and divide it with the length of names list, and assign it to the parent container of text and it will take all the available space.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; //Total available width of device
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: names.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: (deviceWidth / names.length) - 16, // 16 is subtracted to adjust the padding space 
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text(names[index])),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      List<String> names = ["first","second","third","fourth"]; //Your names list here
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / names.length) - 16, // Ratio of width relative to array of names
//Since 8 paddings are given from the right and left, I subtract 16.
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text(names[index])),
                  ),
                );
    
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
      }
    }
```

As I mentioned in the comment lines, I create an array of names myself. In the Width part, I specified the ratio of the width to the names array to be compatible with each screen using MediaQuery. Enjoy your work.

Output:

[image]

Comment: It will overflow for sure since it's width will also include the padding amount which is defined as 8 from all sides, and there for you must subtract that padding.

Comment: Yes, I'm updating that part now.